Reference request non existence of minimal resolution.
In this page of Wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_of_singularities), it writes, the hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^4$ defined by the equation $xy-zw$ has no minimal resolution.
Do you know any reference that have a proof of this fact.
If possible, a standard reference of birational geometry, singularity theory , minimal model probelem, is appreciated.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_(mathematics)#Examples, with a reference therein.
